# Is there any alternative for Keystone wsgi service for production usage?

Tags: openstack, keystone

I am installing keystone inside a docker container using the  `centos-release-openstack-queens rpms` ... it installs couple of scripts `/usr/bin/keystone-wsgi-public`, `/usr/bin/keystone-wsgi-admin` .. which start the `wsgi` services for keystone.
But, I see message displayed there "DANGER! For testing only, do not use in production" .. are these not really meant for production .. if so is there an alternative available?

Answer (score 2):

You should be using a web server to host Keystone within your container. You could either use Apache (with mod_wsgi) or Nginx (with uwsgi). The Keystone services are never meant to be run themselves, and is only meant for debugging, or very basic use-cases.

There are plenty of resources on how to run Keystone within a container, but as a reference you could take a look at Kolla.
https://github.com/openstack/kolla

You can also just use the official guides as a reference.
https://docs.openstack.org/keystone/queens/install/index-rdo.html

Comment: Thanks for the quick help !